# Multibib cite not working on Latex-Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to use Multibib to separate the references, one for the paper and another for the appendix. The new command is not working, it doesn't find the bib entries from the related bib file.

Here is the smallest version of the overleaf project.
I use two different bib files: one for referencing through the paper and another for the SLR appendix part.

Then I created the new command:

```
\usepackage{multibib}  
\newcites{slr}{Appendix References}
```

I used this command like:

An example with cite~\cite{10.1145/130844.130856}, and here is the citeslr~\citeslr{Mora_Segura201679}

And, at the Appendix part I wrote:

'''

```
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}
\clearpage
\appendix
\continuouslabelsfalse
\section{Selected Studies}
\label{append:slr}
\bibliographyslr{SLR}
```

'''

Find attached the minimal example here:

https://www.overleaf.com/3393931684gxnfmjfnbdyf

Hope for your support.

Comment: Please add a [mre] directly to your question to make sure your question stays useful for future users even if the link stops working.

Comment: Follow the damn train, CJ: https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multibib

Comment: Could you solve this problem, @py2018 ? I have done exactly the same as you (and what Overleaf itself recommends on their website, link in another comment) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a bibliography 'plain' style

```latex
\bibliographystyleslr{plain}
```